# How to take input from dropdown list compare it to a value in the database and then run commands using the other relating values of the same model?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

So I have this Model:

```
class Mymodel(models.Model):
    brand = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    model = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    year = models.PositiveIntegerField()
```

and I have a dropdown as such:

```
<select>
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

I want the user to be able to click a button, and it take their input from the dropdown. Then compare it to values in the database, and once it finds one that matches to return the other values related to that one. And lastly have a way to use them in a function in the views.py file.

Comment: This question is way too broad. It's basically asking 'how does django work'. Have you had a go at writing a view, creating a django form/ modelform, and rendering it to a template?

Comment: On a side note, and I mean no disrespect here, but have you completed the entire django tutorial? It covers all of the above in quite a lot of detail.

Comment: @Asher, I have finished it but maybe I forget some things so I'll go back and read thru it again, thank you for the advice.